# Why does gpytorch seem to be less accurate than scikit-learn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pytorch

I current found gpytorch (https://github.com/cornellius-gp/gpytorch). It seems to be a great package for integrating GPR into pytorch. First tests were also positive. Using gpytorch the GPU-Power as well as intelligent algorithms can used in order to improve performance in comparison to other packages such as scikit-learn.

However, I found that it is much harder to estimate the hyperparameters that are needed. In scikit-learn that happens in the background and is very robust. I would like get some feed from the community about the reasons and to discuss if there might be a better way to estimatethese parameter than provided by the example in the documentation of gpytorch.

For comparisson, I took the code of a provided example on the offcial page of gpytorch (https://github.com/cornellius-gp/gpytorch/blob/master/examples/03_Multitask_GP_Regression/Multitask_GP_Regression.ipynb) and modified it in two parts:

1. I use a different kernel (gpytorch.kernels.MaternKernel(nu=2.5) in stead of gpytorch.kernels.RBFKernel())
2. I used a different output function

In the following, I provide first the code using gpytorch. Subsequently, I provide the code for scikit-learn. Finally, I compare the results

Importing (for gpytorch and scikit-learn):

```
import math
import torch
import numpy as np
import gpytorch
```

Generating data (for gpytorch and scikit-learn):

```
n = 20
train_x = torch.zeros(pow(n, 2), 2)
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        # Each coordinate varies from 0 to 1 in n=100 steps
        train_x[i * n + j][0] = float(i) / (n-1)
        train_x[i * n + j][1] = float(j) / (n-1)

train_y_1 = (torch.sin(train_x[:, 0]) + torch.cos(train_x[:, 1]) * (2 * math.pi) + torch.randn_like(train_x[:, 0]).mul(0.01))/4
train_y_2 = torch.sin(train_x[:, 0]) + torch.cos(train_x[:, 1]) * (2 * math.pi) + torch.randn_like(train_x[:, 0]).mul(0.01)

train_y = torch.stack([train_y_1, train_y_2], -1)

test_x = torch.rand((n, len(train_x.shape)))
test_y_1 = (torch.sin(test_x[:, 0]) + torch.cos(test_x[:, 1]) * (2 * math.pi) + torch.randn_like(test_x[:, 0]).mul(0.01))/4
test_y_2 = torch.sin(test_x[:, 0]) + torch.cos(test_x[:, 1]) * (2 * math.pi) + torch.randn_like(test_x[:, 0]).mul(0.01)
test_y = torch.stack([test_y_1, test_y_2], -1)
```

Now comes the estimation as described in the provided example from the cited documentation:

```
torch.manual_seed(2) # For a more robust comparison
class MultitaskGPModel(gpytorch.models.ExactGP):
    def __init__(self, train_x, train_y, likelihood):
        super(MultitaskGPModel, self).__init__(train_x, train_y, likelihood)
        self.mean_module = gpytorch.means.MultitaskMean(
            gpytorch.means.ConstantMean(), num_tasks=2
        )
        self.covar_module = gpytorch.kernels.MultitaskKernel(
            gpytorch.kernels.MaternKernel(nu=2.5), num_tasks=2, rank=1
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        mean_x = self.mean_module(x)
        covar_x = self.covar_module(x)
        return gpytorch.distributions.MultitaskMultivariateNormal(mean_x, covar_x)


likelihood = gpytorch.likelihoods.MultitaskGaussianLikelihood(num_tasks=2)
model = MultitaskGPModel(train_x, train_y, likelihood)

# Find optimal model hyperparameters
model.train()
likelihood.train()

# Use the adam optimizer
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam([
    {'params': model.parameters()},  # Includes GaussianLikelihood parameters
], lr=0.1)

# "Loss" for GPs - the marginal log likelihood
mll = gpytorch.mlls.ExactMarginalLogLikelihood(likelihood, model)

n_iter = 50
for i in range(n_iter):
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    output = model(train_x)
    loss = -mll(output, train_y)
    loss.backward()
    # print('Iter %d/%d - Loss: %.3f' % (i + 1, n_iter, loss.item()))
    optimizer.step()

# Set into eval mode
model.eval()
likelihood.eval()

# Make predictions
with torch.no_grad(), gpytorch.settings.fast_pred_var():
    predictions = likelihood(model(test_x))
    mean = predictions.mean
    lower, upper = predictions.confidence_region()

test_results_gpytorch = np.median((test_y - mean) / test_y, axis=0)
```

In the following, I provide the code for scikit-learn. Which is a little bit more convenient^^:

```
from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcessRegressor
from sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels import WhiteKernel, Matern
kernel = 1.0 * Matern(length_scale=0.1, length_scale_bounds=(1e-5, 1e5), nu=2.5) \
         + WhiteKernel()
gp = GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=kernel, alpha=0.0).fit(train_x.numpy(),
                                                            train_y.numpy())
# x_interpolation = test_x.detach().numpy()[np.newaxis, :].transpose()
y_mean_interpol, y_std_norm = gp.predict(test_x.numpy(), return_std=True)

test_results_scitlearn = np.median((test_y.numpy() - y_mean_interpol) / test_y.numpy(), axis=0)
```

Finally I compare the results:

```
comparisson = (test_results_scitlearn - test_results_gpytorch)/test_results_scitlearn
print('Variable 1: scitkit learn is more accurate my factor: ' + str(abs(comparisson[0]))
print('Variable 2: scitkit learn is more accurate my factor: ' + str(comparisson[1]))
```

Unfortunatelly, I did not find an easy way to fix the seed for scikit-learn. The last time I have run the code, it returned:

> Variable 1: scitkit learn is more accurate my factor: 11.362540360431087
>
> Variable 2: scitkit learn is more accurate my factor: 29.64760087022618

In case of gpytorch, I assume that the optimizer runs in some local optima. But I cannot think of any more robust optimization algorithm that still uses pytorch.

I am looking forward for suggestions!

Lazloo

Comment: Discussions and Suggestions are both things we avoid. Not sure how this "question" fits into [ask]... lots of code lots of efford - not really a clear problem/question I can see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(I also answer your question on the GitHub issue you created for it [here](https://github.com/cornellius-gp/gpytorch/issues/481))

Primarily this happened because you used different models in sklearn and gpytorch. In particular, sklearn learns independent GPs in the multi-output setting by default (see e.g., the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50185399/multiple-output-gaussian-process-regression-in-scikit-learn)). In GPyTorch, you used the multitask GP method introduced in [Bonilla et al, 2008](https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/ckiw/postscript/multitaskGP_v22.pdf). Correcting for this difference yields:

> test_results_gpytorch = [5.207913e-04 -8.469360e-05]
>
> test_results_scitlearn = [3.65288816e-04 4.79017145e-05]