# Returning std from sklearn gaussian process regression for mutliple targets?

Tags: scikit-learn

I'm using scikit learn to fit a Gaussian process regressor to some data. Ideally I want to do this for data with multiple targets, however the prediction doesn't seem return the std for multiple targets. As an example here I train a Gaussian process on 3 target statistics and predict at 100 sampled positions

```
gpr = GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=kernel)
gpr.fit(x.reshape(-1,1), y_obs)
y,y_err=gpr.predict(x_sample.reshape(-1,1),return_std=True)
```

Where the training data has shape `x.shape=(20,)` and `y_obs.shape=(20,3)`. The predicted mean and errors `(y,y_sample)` then do not have the same shape.

```
print(y.shape)
print(y_err.shape)
```

returns

```
(100,3)
(100,)
```

The mean, `y`, is the shape I expect as I requested the 3 targets at 100 sampled positions. However `y_err` doesn't seem be predicted for each target statistic.

This doesn't seem to be working as the documentation describes as both the mean and std should have shape (n_samples,) or (n_samples, n_targets)

Is this a bug, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, this is a bug (see https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/22199 and other related issues), fixed not so long ago. Sklearn 1.1.0 and up should return the proper shape. (However, multitarget GPR seems to be [problematic in general](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50185399) so you may potentially encounter other issues still.)